# ploting a line graph in using ggplot or dygraph having matrix as input

Tags: r, ggplot2, dygraphs

I have a matrix of 6 columns and 5 rows. The first column is week index and rest are percentage changes. It may look like this:

I want to create a aesthetically pleasing line graphs in R using either ggplot or dygraph with labelled axis and colored lines (for 2nd to 6th column)

Any extended help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your request of an "aesthetically pleasing" graph is a little vague, but here is how you could produce a labelled and colourful plot using ggplot2.

First simulate some data to fit the format you describe:

```
set.seed(2015)
df = data.frame(week = 1:5, 
                pct1 = sample(1:100, 5), 
                pct2 = sample(1:100, 5), 
                pct3 = sample(1:100, 5), 
                pct4 = sample(1:100, 5), 
                pct5 = sample(1:100, 5))

df
  week pct1 pct2 pct3 pct4 pct5
1    1    7   36   71   89   70
2    2   84   50   39   27   41
3    3   30    8    4    8   21
4    4    4   64   40   79   65
5    5   14   99   72   37   71
```

To produce the desired plot with ggplot2, you should convert the data to a "long" format. I use the function `gather` from the package `tidyr` (you could also use the equivalent `melt` function from package `reshape2`).

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Gather the data.frame to long format
df_gathered = gather(df, pct_type, pct_values, pct1:pct5)

head(df_gathered)
  week pct_type pct_values
1    1     pct1          7
2    2     pct1         84
3    3     pct1         30
4    4     pct1          4
5    5     pct1         14
6    1     pct2         36
```

Now you can easily produce a plot by colouring using the `pct_type` variable.

```
ggplot(data = df_gathered, aes(x = week, y = pct_values, colour = pct_type)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(size = 1) + xlab("Week index") + ylab("Whatever (%)")
```

[image: ggplot2_example]

**Note:**
In case the variable `week` is a factor (I assumed it was a number, as you referred to it as "week index"), you would also need to tell `ggplot` to group data by `pct_type`, like so:

```
ggplot(data = df_gathered, aes(x = week, y = pct_values, 
                               colour = pct_type, group = pct_type)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(size = 1) + xlab("Week index") + ylab("Whatever (%)")
```